# Finding non-dominated points in 2D vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have to generate 100 random points in n-demensional space (for this program I will set 2-dimensions for better understanding - so 1 point has 2 coordinates) and find non-dominated points. What is non-dominated point? If we have points `(x0,y0),...,(x99,y99)`, pair `i` is dominated by pair `j` if `xi<xj` and `yi<yj`. To find non-dominated points we can compare them all with each other (without comparing the same points).

So I thought to create two 2D vectors to store in both of them the same points (`points` and `temp`), compare them with each other and if currently checked point is not-dominated by all of the others - put it to `nondominated` container. The problem is I don't how to compare them.

Here is small piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;

double genRand() {
    double temp = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX * 100.0 - 50.0;
    return temp;
}

void fill_row(vector<double> & row) {
    generate(row.begin(), row.end(), genRand);
}

void fill_matrix(vector<vector<double>> & matrix) {
    for_each(matrix.begin(), matrix.end(), fill_row);
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    vector<vector<double>> points(100, vector<double>(2));
    vector<vector<double>> temp(100, vector<double>(2));
    vector<vector<double>> nondominated;

    fill_matrix(points);
    copy(points.begin(), points.end(), temp.begin());

    return 0;
}
```

Note: I can't use any loop in this program - only STL algorithms.

Comment: _"Note: I can't use any loop in this program - only STL algorithms."_ What silly restriction is this coming from?

Comment: From a lecturer

Comment: Are they somehow a luminary in the topic I have been  overlooking so far?

Comment: `std::find_if` sounds like it has potential. tactical note: `vector<vector<double>>` with an inner dimension of two has the potential to be hilariously slow due to poor spacial locality `vector<pair<double,double>>` is likely a better choice as it will be one contiguous block of memory. Modern CPUs love that.

Comment: @user4581301 But how to use `find_if` when it looks like it can operate only on one container?

Comment: You only need one container.

Answer (score 0):

Using remove_if:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;

vector< pair<double,double> > points(100);

double genRand()
{
    double temp = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX * 100.0 - 50.0;
    return temp;
}

void fill_row(pair<double,double> & row)
{
    row.first = genRand();
    row.second = genRand();
}

void fill_matrix(vector< pair<double,double> > & matrix)
{
    for_each(matrix.begin(), matrix.end(), fill_row);
}

bool IsDominated( pair<double,double>&  testpoint )
{
    // check if test point is dominated by any other point
    if ( any_of(points.begin(), points.end(), [ testpoint ](pair<double,double>& ip )
    {
        // is the test point dominated by iterated point
        // both x and y must be greated in order to dominate
        return ( ip.first > testpoint.first && ip.second > testpoint.second );
    }) )
        return true;

    // no other points dominated
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    // generate some random points
    fill_matrix(points);

    // display points
    for_each( points.begin(), points.end(), []( pair<double,double>& ip )
    {
        cout << ip.first <<","<< ip.second <<" ";
    });
    cout << "\n";

    // remove the dominated points
    auto pend = remove_if(points.begin(), points.end(), IsDominated );
    pend--;

    std::cout << "\nUndominated points:\n";
    for_each( points.begin(), pend, []( pair<double,double>& ip )
    {
        cout << ip.first <<","<< ip.second <<" ";
    });

    return 0;
}
```

For n dimensions you will have to replace `pair<double,double>` with your own class.